# Combine two arrays into one array of objects with two properties

Tags: bash

I have two arrays:

```
arrayNumberNames=['one', 'two', 'three']
arrayDigits=[1,2,3]
```

I want to combine them into an array that looks like this:

```
arrayNumbers=[
   {
       name: 'one'
       digit: 1,
   },
   {
       name: 'two'
       digit: 2,
   },
   {
       name: 'three'
       digit: 3,
   }
]
```

Comment: That looks neither like a JSON array nor a Bash one.

Comment: the jq tag was by mistake, but what do you mean by "nor a bash one" ?

Comment: In Bash, the array definition syntax is `arrayNumberNames=(one two three)`; no square brackets, no commas.

Answer (score 2):

In bash you can create associative array like this:

```
declare -A arrayNumbers
```

And populate it like this

```
for i in ${arrayDigits[@]}; { arrayNumbers[${arrayNumberNames[$i]}]=$i; }
```

Array will look like this

```
arrayNumbers=( [one]=1 [two]=2 [three]=3 )
```